# Scripting changes to the vNIC in vSphere for a cloned VM

Tags: networking, vmware-vsphere, clone, powercli

After deploying a Windows VM clone from a template, how can a script be written to change the network the vNIC is on ("Network label" in the VM Settings window) and enable the NIC?

I'm working with templates built in one environment that need to be deployed into many in an automated fashion, and the network needs to be reassigned automatically for the vSphere cluster the VM is deployed to.

Comment: Not sure why there is a downvote or a VtC for "not constructive" - I know many others who have run into similar issues before and since asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this function for deployment scripts which takes the IP address and does a lookup in an external file. Here's the code...

```
Function Get-NetworkName
{
param($vmip)

$ip      = $vmip
$ipArray = $ip.Split(".")
$subnet  = $ipArray[0] + "." + $ipArray[1] + "." + $ipArray[2]

$path     = "vlanmapping.txt"
$vlanhash = ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData ([io.file]::ReadAllText($path))

$networkname = $vlanhash.Get_Item($subnet)

return $networkname
}

$vmname = "my_vm"
$vmip = "10.10.1.100"
Get-VM -name $vmname | Get-NetworkAdapter | Set-NetworkAdapter -NetworkName (Get-NetworkName($vmip)) -confirm:$false


#Contents of vlanmapping.txt
#10.10.10=VLAN1
#10.10.20=VLAN2
#10.10.30=VLAN3
```

BE CAREFUL! This works well with a VM with 1 NIC only. The Get-NetworkAdapter cmdlet returns all NICs so all NICs will have their Network set.
Hope ok.

Comment: Is this in PowerShell?

Comment: It certainly is with the [PowerCLI plugin](http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/server/vsphere/automationtools/powercli) of course